# E0137 expression must be a modifiable L-value

Tags: c++, vector

Im writing a small change to a code in visual studio and Im getting this error:

```
Error (active) E0137 expression must be a modifiable L-value
C:\Users\...\events.cpp 75
```

This is the piece of code I added: (In bold is the line I'm getting the error):

```
void EV_HLDM_MuzzleFlash(vec3_t pos, float amount)
{
    dlight_t *dl = gEngfuncs.pEfxAPI->CL_AllocDlight(0);
    dl->origin = pos;  // ERROR HERE
    dl->color.r = 255; // red
    dl->color.g = 255; // green
    dl->color.b = 128; // blue
    dl->radius = amount * 100;
    dl->die = gEngfuncs.GetClientTime() + 0.01;
}
```

And here is the definition of `dlight`:

```
typedef float vec3_t[3]; 

typedef struct dlight_s
{
    vec3_t  origin;
    float   radius;
    color24 color;
    float   die;                // stop lighting after this time
    float   decay;              // drop this each second
    float   minlight;           // don't add when contributing less
    int     key;
    qboolean    dark;           // subtracts light instead of adding
} dlight_t;
```

I don't really understand what´s wrong. I'm defining `origin` as a `vector` for the struct `dlight` and then I'm giving a `vector` in `EV_HLDM_MuzzleFlash`. I don't understand what the problem is. Please help.

I tried changing the first line in `dlight_t` to `Vector` and the previous error dissapear, but I got new errors:

```
Error C3646 'origin': unknown override specifier 
Error C4430 Missing type specifier; int is assumed Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

I get 46 times those 2 errors when changing from `vec3_t` to `Vector`.

What am I missing?

Comment: How is the type `vec3_t` defined?  Don't describe it, *show it*.

Comment: Seems like `dl->origin` is const?

Comment: @dbush typedef float vec3_t[3];

Comment: @Jason Why would it be a const? I mean there it is origin defined in the second code and I dont see its a const but well Im not an expert I dont know maybe I have to specify it is not a const?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `origin` field is defined as an array, and arrays can't be assigned to directly.  You'll need to use `memcpy` to copy the array elements.

```
memcpy(dl->origin, pos, sizeof dl->origin);
```

Comment: Or `std::copy()`. Alternatively, change `vec3_t` to `std::array<float, 3>`, which can be assigned to.